# Index out of range error received, but I can't find out why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexoutofrangeexception

I was hoping somebody can help me with the following:

I have the following data in some lists in lists --> A

```
A = [[['Ghost Block'], ['Ghost Block'], [-7.0, -30000.0, 84935.99999999991, 1.0, 5.0, 0, 84935.99999999991, 1, 1, ['Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost']], [-5.0, -30000.0, 84935.99999999991, 1.0, 4.0, -30000.0, 114935.99999999991, 2, 1, ['Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost']], [-3.0, 33475.49999999997, 84935.99999999991, 1.0, 3.0, -60000.0, 144935.9999999999, 3, 1, ['Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost']], [-1.0, 80158.49999999997, 84935.99999999991, 1.0, 2.0, -26524.50000000003, 111460.49999999994, 4, 1, ['Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost']], [1.0, 31301.99999999997, 84935.99999999991, 1.0, 1.0, 53633.99999999994, 31301.99999999997, 5, 1, ['Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost']]]]
TempValue = 0
Ghost_Block = -60000
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    for item in range(0,len(A[i])):
        if A[i][item] == 'Ghost Block':
            continue
        else:
            if A[i][item][9][0] == 'Ghost': # Neighbor 1
                TempValue += (Ghost_Block*A[i][item][4])
```

I receive the following error message:

```
--> 9             if Value_Spec_Depth[i][item][9][0] == 'Ghost': # Neighbor 1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

According to me Value_Spec_Depth[i][item][9][0] is not out of range. I hope someone can explain to me why I am receiving this error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `item` values `0` and `1`, `A[i][item]` is `['Ghost Block']`, not `'Ghost Block'` (note the 1-value list), so your `if` test never passes and the `else` block is executed instead:

```
>>> A[0][0]
['Ghost Block']
>>> A[0][1]
['Ghost Block']
```

As a result, the `else` suite tries to access index 9 of a list with only one.

You'd avoid this by actually testing for the list:

```
if A[i][item] == ['Ghost Block']:
```

or test the first element of a list:

```
if A[i][item][0] == 'Ghost Block':
```

Note that you can just loop over the lists *directly*, you don't need to produce indices. You also don't need to use `continue` if you just test for the *inverse*:

```
for sublist in A:
    for element in sublist:
        if element[0] != 'Ghost Block' and element[9][0] == 'Ghost':
            TempValue += Ghost_Block * element[4]
```

Another improvement would be to use custom classes instead of lists; it is not clear at all from using indices what meaning each value has.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I still don't understand fully since I am now trying:

TempValue = 0

for i in Value_Spec_Depth:

    for item in i:

        if item == 'Ghost Block':

            continue

        else:

            print item[9][0]

and it gives me the errror list index out of range.  What I do is basicly what you are saying in your 3rd line in the if statment behind the 'and'. element[9][0] where in my code I put item[9][0], but I receive list index out of range. Could you explain this to me please?

Comment: @AlmostGr: `if item[0] == 'Ghost Block'`. `item` is still a list.

Comment: But then it doesn't look at [9] at all ( are you sure you are not misreading 'Ghost Block' for 'Ghost'). Because at index 9 there is a list within the item list? I don't understand how [0] will make it possible for me to iterate through the other elements in the index [9].

Comment: @AlmostGr: You want to *skip* lists that don't have `item[9]`, because that causes your index error. Either use `if len(item) > 9` to make sure you have enough elements, or detect the short 1-element list by that first value. Your choice. Yes, I'm sure it is `'Ghost Block'` because that's the value at index 0 for those 1-element lists.

Comment: Thank you for your help Martijn

Comment: If you don't mind, one more question:
Since I got in my previous code the following:

if A[i][item] == 'Ghost Block':
            continue
        else:

every A[i][item] that does not equal ['Ghost Block'] has got a [9] index so aren't I already skipping lists that don't have item[9] and should my code not get the error 'list index out of range'?

Comment: @AlmostGr: you were testing if `A[i][item]` does not equal `'Ghost Block'` (note, **no list**), while you should have been checking if it is equal `['Ghost Block']` (a list with one element, a string).